# If I revoke the existing iOS Dev Center Development Certificate, will that screw up any other developers using it?

Tags: ios, certificate, code-signing, ios-provisioning

I work for a large, spread out (all over the country) company.

We have a paid iOS Dev Center account and I've been using it to develop iOS apps on phones for months now.

I've now returned to an iOS project after some weeks and it appears that while I was away the existing Development Certificate (the one you use to test and debug on phones, not the Distribution Certificate for the App Store) expired, and someone renewed it.

And now when I download that certificate, it doesn't match the private/public key pair on my system. My guess is that whoever did it generated a new key pair (whether or not they needed to do this I don't know).

So now I guess I need to hunt down the person who did this (it's in the name of the person who signed up for the account but that's not necessarily who did it) so I can get them to export their key pair.

Or I could revoke the certificate and make a new one.

If I do that, will it screw up anyone who's working with the (now revoked) certificate/key pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anybody else who is developing with the new profile should also have the newly created new keys. so you don't necessarily have to hunt down the original person who revoked the old cert.
But if even that is problem then i suggest you revoke and send out the new .p12 to everybody who might need it. And as long as it does not affect the old apps (which it wont) you should be ok.

But on a sidenote your company needs a system to be able to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure - if you revoke his certificate, it will simply not be valid and clients will receive errors about unsigned / revoked signing on the app.